# Why does referencing a property of an object literal behave differently in different contexts?

Tags: javascript, object, browser

If I run `{"a": "b", "c": "d"}.a` in a browser (tested in Chrome and Firefox), I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'`. But if I run it in Node.js, it works as expected. If I put it in a function call, such as `console.log({"a": "b", "c": "d"}.a)`, now it works fine even in the browser.

What's going on here?

Comment: Browser consoles are weird, don't use them for things like this.

Comment: If you start a statement with `{` it thinks it's the beginning of a block, not an object literal.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Comment: To clarify, my question isn't "should I do this?" or "what else could braces mean?". I'm asking why different environments handle this syntax differently. Are browser consoles just implementing the JS standards incorrectly? If so, why?

Comment: A leading `{` introduces either a block statement, or an object initializer. In a browser console, it's going to be a block statement. In an argument list to `console.log()` (which is *also* true in the browser context), it's an object initializer. The grammar is ambiguous, so the parser always assumes a block statement unless it's obviously supposed to be an expression.

Comment: @Pointy So why does Node handle it differently?

Comment: In `console.log({ something: "whatever" })` the object initializer is an argument to `console.log()`, so the *only thing it can possibly be* is an object initializer. When a parser sees `{` *without* any context like that, it will assume that it's seeing the beginning of a block of code, and *not* an object initializer.